# how to set the width and height of ImageView and TextView here?

Tags: android, dynamic-data

here are my text and image and text views(i1, t1, t2). how can i format the width and height of these views dynamically in my class file.

```
          ImageView i1 = new ImageView(this);
          TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
            RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams innerLP1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            innerLP1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            innerLP1.topMargin=(30);
            t1.setText(name);
            rl1.setLayoutParams(innerLP1);
            rl1.addView(t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

set layout parameters to those views

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams view_params = new 
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageview.setLayoutParams(view_params );
textview.setLayoutParams(view_params );
```

Comment: i have already added my image and textviews in RelativeLayout rl1. should i make another RelativeLayout again and then set height and width?? and where shall i set the integer value of text and image size??

Comment: that is also ok np, for text size tv.setTextSize(15); use this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `txt.SetHeight()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use setHeight() & setWidth() methods. For example:

```
     ImageView i1 = new ImageView(this);
     i1.setHeight(xxx);
     i1.setWidth(xxx);
```

Comment: add your image & textviews to Relativelayout and apply the above code. it will work..